# Neo4j Server Startup Exception

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

Iam unable to start the neo4j server..iam using java 1.7 and neo4j 2.0.0 when i run the sample java with maven example, iam getting this problem. Here is the log file

```
Oct 09, 2013 8:49:14 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
Oct 09, 2013 8:49:15 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: 
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@ce8273' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:211)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@ce8273' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:280)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:207)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.recovery.StoreRecoverer.recover(StoreRecoverer.java:114)
    at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.run(PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreFlightTasks.run(PreFlightTasks.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:276)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:162)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@ce8273' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:258)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@1f5329f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:128)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException: Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true"
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.ConfigMapUpgradeConfiguration.checkConfigurationAllowsAutomaticUpgrade(ConfigMapUpgradeConfiguration.java:39)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.attemptUpgrade(StoreUpgrader.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.tryToUpgradeStores(StoreFactory.java:113)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:96)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:240)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
    ... 15 more

Oct 09, 2013 8:49:15 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
```

How to clear this?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/deployment-upgrading.html),

```
set the Neo4j configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true" in your neo4j.properties or embedded configuration
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply Vidya..i already set that "allow_store_upgrade=true" then iam getting, "Not all store files match the version required for successful upgrade exception."

Comment: If @Vidya answered your original question correctly, would you please consider accepting that answer? If you have follow up questions you can keep asking, but please mind the difference between 'getting your stuff to work' and having your question answered. Cheers.

Comment: What exact versions are you upgrading from and to?

Comment: @jjaderberg vidya's answer didnt worked for me,its throwing exception like   "Not all store files match the version required for successful upgrade exception."  and iam not upgrading the versions, iam just executing sample application provided with java 1.7 and neo4j version 2.0.0, then iam getting the above exception

Comment: Yes, but that's a different exception than in your original question and I think @Vidya's answer correctly resolves the original `UgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException`. But no matter, I'll help if I can: I don't know what sample application you mean, do you have a link to it? Is it java code that you compile and run?

Comment: here is the link for the sample program ..https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.0.0-M05/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java

Answer (score 1):

In general with Neo4j, a database can be upgraded from a minor version to the next, e.g. 1.7 → 1.8, and 1.8 → 1.9, but you can not jump directly from 1.7 → 2.0.

You have two options:

1. upgrade to each minor version in succession setting the Neo4j configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true" as in @Vidya's answer, or
2. re-import your data into the new 2.0 version of Neo4j.